# Image doesn't appear in ImageView after it is taken by the camera

Tags: java, opencv, javafx

Hello I've start using OpenCv and I wanted to take a photo from the camera and show it in an ImageView that was already created in SceneBuilder but it doesn't appear. There is no apparent error.

```
private class Photo {
    private Mat matrix = null;
    private VideoCapture c = null;

    public void takePhoto() {
        Photo p = new Photo();
        WritableImage wii = p.capturePhoto();

        p.saveImage();

        image = new ImageView(wii);
    }

    private WritableImage capturePhoto() {
        WritableImage wiiU = null;
        System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
        c = new VideoCapture(0);
        Mat matrix = new Mat();
        c.read(matrix);

        if(c.isOpened()) {
            if(c.read(matrix)) {
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(matrix.width(), matrix.height(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                WritableRaster r = img.getRaster();
                DataBufferByte db = (DataBufferByte) r.getDataBuffer();
                byte[] bd = db.getData();
                matrix.get(0, 0, bd);
                this.matrix = matrix;

                wiiU = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(img, null);
            }
        }
        return wiiU;
    }

    private void saveImage() {
        String file = ".//images//photo.png";
        Imgcodecs imageCodecs = new Imgcodecs();
        imageCodecs.imwrite(file, matrix);
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a new image view (`image = new ImageView(wii)`), but you never appear to display it anywhere. Can you show where you add this to the scene graph?

Comment: I created an FXML document using SceneBuilder and I added it to an anchorpane. What I was trying to do was to change the content of that imageView.      <ImageView fitHeight="132.0" fitWidth="161.0" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="38.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../images/UserProfile.png" />
         </image>

Comment: But (as I pointed out in the previous comment), you create a new `ImageView` in code. So even if `image` used to be the `ImageView` you create in the FXML, you reassign it so it no longer refers to that image view. If you want to change the content of an existing image view, you would just do `imageView.setImage(...)`.

Comment: I understand what you said. I've try it and I get this exception. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at graphicInterface.ControllerSignUpPatient$Photo.takePhoto(ControllerSignUpPatient.java:112)
 at graphicInterface.ControllerSignUpPatient.onTakePhotoClick(ControllerSignUpPatient.java:226) This occurs in the line where I do image.setImage(wii); Why is this happening?

Comment: Because `image` is null.

Comment: Because `<ImageView>` does not have a `fx:id` attribute. Furthermore it's not declared in the code you posted...